# Error while trying to run package with dtexec

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I'm attempting to run a package from command line with plans to schedule the run via batch.

I enter the following

```
dtexec /Project "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Batch\ScheduleRun\ScheduledRun\ScheduledRun" /Package "batchrun.dtsx"
```

generates this error

Started:  11:18:01 AM
Could not load project "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Batch\ScheduleRun\ScheduledRun\ScheduledRun" because of error 0x80070005.
Description: Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Batch\ScheduleRun\ScheduledRun\ScheduledRun' is denied.
Source: mscorlib
Started:  11:18:01 AM
Finished: 11:18:01 AM
Elapsed:  0.047 seconds

I tried running CMD as admin and I get the same error. Any idea what may be the cause of this?

Thanks
SJ

Comment: Even though it's running as admin, you might still need to explicitly grant access to the path. Think about if you were to navigate this path through Windows Explorer - even though you have permissions, it may still prompt you the first time and ask whether you want to try to go there. I suspect the same thing is happening here. Try moving the Batch and child folders to somewhere more neutral like C:\temp and then see whether the problem remains. If not, then it's permissions. If it remains, then something is awry with the command invocation.

Comment: I would expect a command line call, for an Project Deployment model package, to look like `/Project \path\to\project\bin\Development\MyProject.ispac /package PackageName.dtsx`  Currently, you have no .ispac extension on your project path